# How to change a local repository name on GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I'm currently using GitHub for Windows to track a few local repositories. However, I'm having a slight problem: whenever I drag and drop a folder I want to track into the UI, the repo automatically takes the name of the folder.

E.g. the following repo is based on a folder called "v2":

[image: Example repo name]

How can I change the repo name to better reflect the project name, without modifying the target folder?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this yet?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik no sir!

Comment: The only way I was able to do it was to **(1)** stop tracking the repo, **(2)** rename the folder and **(3)** drag the folder back into GitHub for Windows (start tracking it again but at new location). It seems that GHfW uses folder name to display local repository display name...

Answer (score 0):

you can write repo name in `.git/description`

Comment: I've tried replacing the content of the description file, but GitHub for Windows still doesn't recognize it. Any ideas?

Comment: @wedens: Do we have to just add it as plain text or set some sort of a variable or anything in this *description* file?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik plain text

Comment: Well it doesn't work then... :( All I could do is to rename the folder and re-drag it to GHfW. It seems that display name is taken from folder name.